# SQL attach rows of other table

Tags: mysql, sql, json, join

I've got 2 tables. The main table called "places":

[image]

and a secondary table caled "place_meta":

[image]

When querying a place, I would like to attach the rows of the place_meta table, with the same place_id, to the place result. It should look either like:

```
{
    id: 1,
    slug: "test",
    status: "active",
    name: "test",
    excerpt: "blah blah",
    description: "bla blah blah",
    test_url: "https://test.de",
    test2_url: "https://test2.de"
}
```

or like

```
{
    id: 1,
    slug: "test",
    status: "active",
    name: "test",
    excerpt: "blah blah",
    description: "bla blah blah",
    meta: {
        test_url: "https://test.de",
        test2_url: "https://test2.de"
    }
}
```

Tried it with joins but really have no idea how to get this as wished.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Answer (score 0):

This will work for two predefined metavalues (test_url and test2_url), but is not a dynamic solution if you have several meta fields.

```
SELECT P.*
    ,PM1.meta_value AS 'test_url'
    ,PM2.meta_value AS 'test2_url'
FROM Places P
LEFT JOIN place_meta PM1 ON PM1.place_id = P.id AND PM1.meta_key = 'test_url'
LEFT JOIN place_meta PM2 ON PM2.place_id = P.id AND PM2.meta_key = 'test2_url'
FOR JSON AUTO
```

Comment: There is no requirement to output only certain keys in the question but it seems to be a requirement to return the result as a JSON string

Comment: Thanks for the heads up Joakim, i added a for json to the query to get the same output as his example 1. Im reading OPs question as how he can get the data from the two tables joined in a way to produce the output. But you may be right that he needs help with both the SQL query and the output formatting.

Comment: i need a dynamical solution. If not possible, then it would be fine to just attach all rows as collection as well